# Developing Cordova Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to developing Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015.  I used the blank Cordova App template to create a project without any content and ran the project under Ripple.  It showed several errors of the following two kinds:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
cordova :: Setting the user agent server side failed.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)

How do I solve these questions?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for your trouble. It appears that a bug was introduced to Ripple. We're looking into it. When it's fixed, I will update this answer with steps on how to fix your environment.

Comment: any updates on the fix?

Comment: This should have been fixed a long time ago. Are you still running into it?

Comment: i am getting POST http://localhost:4400/ripple/user-agent 500 (Internal Server Error)    GET http://localhost:4400/config.xml 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you check your firewall settings and make sure that port isn't blocked?

Comment: this is the err msg that goes with err code 500 Cannot prepare sources for the platform: Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "cordova prepare android" 'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: my firewall is off and this is all localhost

Comment: I'm getting the same 500 error with Cordova. How can I fix it?

Comment: How is this the answer? I don't see a fix. Just installed VS 2015 with Cordova today and this problem still exists on a new Cordova project.

Comment: @MichaelBraude the issue still persists...
i was trying to fix it but is beyond my knowledge....
please help.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of missing ripple.js error and other js-missing file related errors, just add this base meta tag to your head section of index.html:

```
<base href="/" target="_blank">
```

Add it **before the other tags** such as scripts and style declarations.

Comment: Could you help with what this line does. and where to add it.

I am a beginner. pleas don't mind if it's silly

Comment: @PrashanthBenny The line goes at the header section of your index.html file. It means that that all relative URLs and sources come from the root dir, the same where index.html is located. Notice that this removes the error but might break some links or other stuff, personally, I don't use ripple anymore, I use the emulators instead.